# How do banking websites hide network calls

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

**No network call recorded while using HDFC Netbanking**

I was going through the network calls made in a banking website.

**I can see the timeline move so the calls are being registered**

When i opened the network call i could see the timeline change, so chrome did register those network calls but i there were no records of them.

I have attached the screenshot of the network call so if anyone can help me out on how are they able to achieve this.

[HDFC netbanking network call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh1u5.jpg)

Comment: If there's no js in a website, there are no calls done after a page is loaded, for example.

Comment: They may use a `form` or `iframe` or many other methods to submit the data. Inspect all requests, not just xhr. Regardless of the method, there's no way to hide the requests.